# MongoDB , $project a field depending on the existance of another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As the title says, i want to project for example the "y" field only if "x" field does not exsist.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "y": "project"
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "x": "has x",
    "y": "don't project"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you like to change the image to be in format code?

Comment: i will , sorry .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can use `$cond` into a `$project` stage to decide if project or not a field:

Here if `x` exists then remove (does not project) the field `y`, otherwise the `y` value is shown.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "y": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {"$gt": ["$x",null]},
          "then": "$$REMOVE",
          "else": "$y"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOxIjyaOcYh)

Note that also you can project the field `x`. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V6GlOyrCN0L)

Comment: That's exactly what i want to achieve thank you !

Comment: I've just changed the fields back to how they were   so people can relate to the old example , and u changed it at the same time 

Comment: I'll change it again to x and y.